# signing multiple domains with dk-milter

Tags: postfix, domainkeys

How can I sign multiple domains using dk-milter so that each domain would have it's own different domainkeys signature.

I've already done this for DKIM using openDKIM (http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2010/09/how-to-get-dkim-domainkeys-identified-mail-working-on-centos-5-5-and-postfix-using-opendkim/) and now I have a different signature for each domain. So no I need to do the same for DomainKeys using the same signatures as DKIM. Doing if for one domain is simple, but for multiple domains I can not find a solution. Each domain already has the public key in the DNS entry from DKIM, so it differs, stopping me from using a single a single signature for all domains if that would be possible.

Here is my dk-milter config file:

```
USER="dk-milt"
PORT="inet:10035@localhost"
SIGNING_DOMAIN="domain.com"
SELECTOR_NAME="default"
KEYFILE="/etc/mail/domainkeys/keys/domain.com/default"
SIGNER=yes
VERIFIER=yes
CANON=simple
REJECTION="bad=r,dns=t,int=t,no=a,miss=r"
EXTRA_ARGS="-h -l -D -i /etc/mail/domainkeys/internal_hosts"
MILTER_GROUP="dk-milt"
```

Thanks

Comment: This is exaclty what I am looking for. If you manage to find the solution for this, please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Hi, just read the above blogs and explanations and you should have no problem doing this, at least I didn't on centos 5.5. Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it.

I installed dk-milter using 1.0.2 rpm that I found.
Then I followed the steps described here http://www.tai.ro/2010/04/03/postfix-with-dkim-domainkeys-spf-and-sender-id/ and I created this configuration for dk-milter:

```
USER="opendkim-milt"
PORT="inet:10035@localhost"
SIGNING_DOMAIN="/etc/mail/dkim/trusted-hosts"
SELECTOR_NAME="default"
KEYFILE="/etc/mail/domainkeys/keylist"
SIGNER=yes
VERIFIER=yes
CANON=simple
REJECTION="bad=r,dns=t,int=t,no=a,miss=r"
EXTRA_ARGS="-h -l -D -k -i /etc/mail/dkim/trusted-hosts"
SYSCONFIG="/etc/sysconfig/dk-milter"
MILTER_GROUP="opendkim-milt"
```

This is the same in /etc/init.d/dk-milter and /etc/syconfig/dk-milter
I used the same user as for opendkim just so that I can read the files directly from dkim directory (the directory must have 700 in orver for the keys to be considered valid)

The only file I have left in the domainkeys directory is keylist that contains rows like this:  *@domain.tld:/var/db/domainkeys/domain.tld/default. And I will probably move this to the dkim directory so that I only use that one.

Now when I need to add a domain I need to follow the next steps:
1. add the directory domain.tld in /etc/mail/dkim/keys/ and generate the keys in that directory then change their owner to opendkim-milt like decribed in the tutorial for dkim
2. add the corresponding lines to /etc/mail/dkim/keyTable signingTable trusted-hosts and /etc/mail/domainkeys/keylist
3. add the public domain key to the DNS entry (from default.txt) and modify it so that it's used for both (just let "k=rsa ; p=...")
4. restart opendkim, dk-milter and postfix services

Everything works great now.
Thanks

Comment: For the DKIM tutorial I followed http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2010/09/how-to-get-dkim-domainkeys-identified-mail-working-on-centos-5-5-and-postfix-using-opendkim/

Comment: Also, if you are using MailScanner you need to change this lines in MailScanner configuraton files, so that it does not modify the mail after it is signed: 
Place New Headers At Top Of Message = yes
Multiple Headers = add
Sign Clean Messages = no